# Social Networks other than facebook and twitter that allow access to their data to developers?

Tags: api, network-structure, social-media

I am looking for social networks, other than Facebook and Twitter, that offer their API to developers, for free. Which other social networks allow developers to crawl data? What kind of restrictions do they have? I am interested in any kind of social network. I would like to collect data for further processing.

Comment: no one touched on restrictions....flickr is going to be the optimal service, you should pin other apis to theirs in terms of stability, implementation, structure, etc. i am not aware of each particular instance listed below, but its imperative to note that they are typically initially offered up for free with no limitations, for mass consumption. the restrictions, including rolling back on currently held api's/terms/etc., only occurs after they get a "business plan" or bought out and lose all their culture (same thing ;) ). its text-book example of the honeypot. mileage varies, course is same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Instagram](http://instagram.com/developer/#)
[Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/)
[Livejournal](http://www.livejournal.com/doc/server/ljp.csp.protocol.html)
[Flikr](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)
[Pinterest](https://developers.pinterest.com/)
[LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)
[Blogger](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/json/using)
[Wordpress](http://developer.wordpress.com/)

Hope it'd be enough to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to I.M.'s list, there also exist:

- Dailymotion
- Metacafe
- Google+
- Tumblr
- Youtube (as distinct from G+)
- Vimeo

My employer is building a service to provide a unified API for these services and more, leave a comment if you would like access to our pre-production API. You get access and I get to learn about your use case and add the features that you need to our API.